# Efficiently find matching indices and values for nested list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, matching

I am working with lists of different sizes and my question is:

Supposing I have two lists of tuples with different sizes:

```
value1 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
value2 = [(0, 6), (0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 9), (0, 7)]
```

Inserted in another list:

```
my_list = [value1, value2]
```

What is the most efficient way (**preferably O(n)**) to find the matching index when appending `mylist` with a `third list` and return then in order? The result should look something like:

```
value3 = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 5), (0, 7), (0, 10)]

mathing_values (my_list, value3): 
    
    my_list.append(value3)

    return ->  "The List 'value3' has a matching with 'value1' in 
                index 0 : (0, 1), index 1: (0, 2) and with 'value2'
                in index 4: (0, 7)"
```

*Obs:* If it works for multiple lists (more than 3) it would be perfect

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's the most efficient way, but readable and straightforward:

```
v3 = set(value3)

[set(x).intersection(v3) for x in my_list]
```

**UPD:** an extended solution with indicies using a dict value as an index:

```rust
v3 = set(value3)

[(i, k) for x in my_list for (i, k) in enumerate(set(x)) if k in v3]
```

Comment: This solved the problem of how to find the matchs (in a really simple way, thanks!), but I really need the indexes, there's any way to allow that?

Comment: Ah, missed that point. You may use a `dict` then, where the *values* a indicies

Comment: Hi @Kitsu, thanks for the answer! Well, I'm receiving the result: **[(0, (0, 1)), (1, (0, 3)), (2, (0, 2)), (0, (0, 7)), (4, (0, 2))]**. However the indices is not maching, the dic is only enumerating the values found. What I want to do is find the specific indices that has a equal match in order, the result should be something like (using your update):
**[[(0, (0, 1)), (1, (0, 2)), (2, (0, 3))], [(1, (0, 2)), (4, (0, 7))]]**. Were: **[[value_1 equal indices and values in order], [value_1 equal indices and values in order]]**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `set()` will work since you are wanting the indices, so this is not super efficient, but it will work:

```
def find_matches(my_list, new_list):
    indices = []
    values = []
    for index, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(my_list[0], my_list[1])):
        for new_value in new_list:
            if new_value == a or new_value == b:
                indices.append(index)
                values.append(new_value)
    if len(indices) == 0:
        return "No matches"
    else:
        return "Matching Values: {} Corresponding Indices: {}".format(values, indices)
```

Then just call the function:

```
print(find_matches(my_list, value3))
```

output:

> Matching Values: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)] Corresponding Indices: [0,
> 1, 2]

Here's the solution with pandas, which will be much faster and can include as many lists as you want. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

def find_matches(my_list, new_list):
    
    #create a dataframe from the lists contained in my_list
    dfs = []
    for l in my_list:
        l_series = pd.Series(l)
        l_df = pd.DataFrame(l_series)
        dfs.append(l_df)
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
    
    #create second df of Boolean values if there are matches to the new_list
    df2 = df[df.isin(new_list)]
    df_final = df2.dropna(how='all')#drop rows where no matches were found in any list

    
    return df_final
```

calling:

```
find_matches(my_list, value3)
```

Return:

```
    0   1
0   (0, 1)  NaN
1   (0, 2)  (0, 2)
2   (0, 3)  NaN
4   NaN (0, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be somewhat slow but should solve the problem. Just only adittional question, and if I have 'n' lists, how the code should be (your code will only work for 3)? I'm asking because probably I will face more than 100 list matching (the reason to looking for a efficient way))

Comment: have you considered using a pandas data frame? Pandas is much faster than native python and would allow you to search indices for all your list matches. You'll just need to convert each list to a Series then add it as a column and then use the pd.index() method where your matches are found

Comment: Hey @darkwing i didn't thinked about using Pandas framework, I will take a look on that. Thanks!

Comment: I added my solution using pandas. It should be a lot faster and you can check the new list for matches in as many lists as you want